# How to send push notification to ionic app from java server using MFP8.0?

Tags: rest, ionic-framework, ibm-mobilefirst

I have my sample **ionic** application which is using service from **REST web service**. Now, I want to send **push notification** from my REST web service to ionic application using **MFP 8.0**.

Is there any Documentaion for this requirement. I searched, but I unable found how to do this through web service.

Anyone help will be Appreciated!!!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not convinced you've searched... Here is where sending notifications via REST is mentioned in the Sending Push Notifications tutorial: https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/notifications/sending-push-notifications/#rest-apis

You did not specify if your application requires authentication or not, so it is best that you will review the entire Notifications category of tutorials.

Comment: I can able to send push notification from mfp to my ionic app. Now I have to send push notification from my webservice to ionic app using mfp. i have red your given documentation link. But i can't able to find the solution, how to do through webservice. I am using java for webservice. Can you provide me any solution?

Comment: Read the Confidential Clients tutorial. It must be able to authenticate against the server before it will be able to use the REST API to send a notification.